# How to Format Numbers Without Scientific Notation or Decimals

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsstring, stringwithformat

My objective is to create a customer calculator application for iPhone and am using Xcode to write my application. My problem that I cannot find a solution for is how to format a number without using scientific notation or a set number of decimals.

I tried...

```
buttonScreen.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f",currentNumber];

buttonScreen.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%g",currentNumber];
```

`%f` formatting always prints 6 digits after the decimal place so if the user types in "5" it displays 5.000000.

`%g` formatting jumps to scientific notation after 6 digits so 1000000 becomes 1e+06 when displayed.

**I want to be able to have the following numbers display without pointless decimals or scientific notation:**

```
123,456,789;
1.23456789;
12345.6789;
-123,456,789;
-1.23456789;
-12345.6789;
```

Comment: I edited your question a bit to conform with the general SO style guidelines and add `%`s to your format strings. If I misrepresented something, please let me know! Also, good first question.

Comment: Well, if you want to avoid decimals I'd suggest octal notation.  You could use binary, of course, but it's not very compact.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For floating point number formatting you can use %f, and you have to specify the minimum field width and the precision in terms of characters. If you use %4.2f, means four characters wide minimum (if less than 4 are used, will be filled with blank spaces at left) and 2 characters for precision. If you want 10 characters of minimum wide and 0 of decimal precision, you use %10.0f .

In your particular case, you should use %.0f for no digits of decimal precision.

```
buttonScreen.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.0f",currentNumber];
```

You can find a quick reference [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fprintf) . Is not the objective-c documentation, but is equivalent.

For the sake of completeness, you can find the documentation of the specification that NSString formatting follows in:

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/FormatStrings.html

and here:

http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/printf.html

### EDIT for truncation:

```
buttonScreen.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",(int)currentNumber];
```

But, you should read a little about floating representation, precision and casting to be aware of possible undesired behavior.

Comment: Hi LuisEspinoza!

I tried using %.0f and it seems to clear up large numbers being written in scientific notation, but when I try to add a decimal to the number (ex. 15,400,179.85) the number gets rounded (so the output is 15,400,180). %.0f

Comment: yes, that's right. What is the behavior that you want to achieve?. For me seems correct to round the decimal whem implementing a calculator with no decimals, but maybe you have something in mind. You want to truncate the number?

Comment: In that case, you should cast the float as integer and print it with %d. But, you should read a little about floating representation, precision and casting to be aware of possible undesired behavior.

Comment: I still would like decimals in the number (no rounding or truncation), without extra 0's (zeros) on the end of the number. I'm sorry for the confusion!

Comment: In that case, i suggest you to accept this answer (clicking in the "check" symbol) and then make a new question. The answer to meet that new requirement will conflict with the current question.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [`NSNumberFormatter`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNumberFormatter_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40003705).

Configured correctly, it can add commas when appropriate. You'll also need to tell it how many significant digits to use.

Answer (score 0):

You aren't interacting with Xcode and Objective-c as much as you suspect here, the underlying implementation is [printf](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/printf/). Check out [this tutorial on how to use printf format specifiers](http://www.codingunit.com/printf-format-specifiers-format-conversions-and-formatted-output).

Answer (score 0):

So what do you want it to look like? The stringWithFormat formatting is a superset of the old C sprintf. So have you tried using d and variations to meet your liking?